# How to find the name of the database from the given table name, using stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, cursors

I am newbie here. I have many databases in my SSMS, so I need to find the database name using the given table name using stored procedures.
And I am not good at writing SP's and handling errors.
I apologize for my English.

Thank you

I tried it using cursors in stored procedure.
But I am getting errors as I am not good at handling errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the stored procedure in the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Get_Tables
    @schema VARCHAR(50) = 'dbo',
    @table_name VARCHAR(100) = 'Default_Table_Name'
AS
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE CASE WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.' + @schema + '.' + @table_name, 'U') END IS NOT NULL
```

And execute the stored procedure you can in the following:

```
EXEC sp_Get_Names 'Schema', 'Table_Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Create PROCEDURE Pro_FindTable
(@tableName VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(MAX),
            @dbid INT;
    DECLARE C CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR(
    SELECT name,
           database_id
    FROM sys.databases);
    OPEN C;
    FETCH NEXT FROM C
    INTO @name,
         @dbid;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
            = 'IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM(SELECT name, COUNT(*)Over(Order By (Select Null)) as RN FROM(SELECT '''
              + @name + ''' AS name UNION ALL SELECT name FROM [' + @name
              + '].sys.tables WHERE type=''U'' AND name = ''' + @tableName
              + ''') as K)as K Where RN>1)
              Select '''+ @name + '''';

        EXEC (@query);

        FETCH NEXT FROM C
        INTO @name,
             @dbid;

    END;
    CLOSE C;
    DEALLOCATE C;

END;
```

And call it like this:

```
EXEC Pro_FindTable 'MyTable'
```

Result will be all databases which has a table named 'MyTable'